# 'SQL Problem' when trying to update Database in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

i am currently learning the basics in ASP.NET and now at manipulating Database.  It doesn't go to the Try section and straight away head to the Catch ex as Exception part which gives me the message box saying "Unsuccessful Operation or SQL problem.

```
    dgvResult.Visible = True
    Try
        conn.Open()
        dd.Connection = conn

        dd.CommandText = "update [STUDENT]" &
        "set [Matric]= '" & txtMatric.Text & "', " &
        "[Name] ='" & txtName.Text & "'," &
        "[Address] ='" & txtAddress.Text & "'," &
        "[Telephone] ='" & txtTelephone.Text & "'," &
        " where [Matric] ='" & txtMatric.Text & "' "

        dd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        dd.Dispose()
        conn.Close()
        MsgBox("Data Updated")



    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Unsucessful Operation or SQL Problem")
    End Try
End Sub
```

My task is to edit some information in database and save it.

Comment: does it hit conn.open()? or fails in dgvResult.visible=true statement?

Comment: That `ex` variable will give you a lot more detail about which line of code threw the error and what it means. I suggest you study it rather than just displaying a message box. Also, don't  form SQL queries via string concatenation. That's just inviting a SQL Injection attack. Learn the proper way to do things from the start. [Use parameterized queries](https://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: The last comma in this line `"[Telephone] ='" & txtTelephone.Text & "'," &` will be one of your problems. As it's the last column in the `SET` section, it does not need to be there

Comment: Also, the line `dd.CommandText = "update [STUDENT]" &` might need a trailing space

Comment: JayV - ah! thank you, that seems to do the trick. I honestly didnt know something so trivial affects the coding. Thank you for helping, I've been stuck at this since yesterday.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.